# Creating a .bat file to open a file and read it then open a .java file

Tags: java, batch-file, cmd

I am trying to create a .bat file to open a .txt file (read the lines) that is in the folder of the .bat file. Following that, then open a Java file (a search method). 
So when I call it in cmd I would type "search.bat test.txt method"

All i have so far is:

```
@echo off
echo "Launching.."
pause 
START "C:\Users\*Username*\Downloads"
```

Comment: You want to do this in Java ? you could just use findstr in *.java. PS please add your java code

Comment: Why not pass the arguments to the java program instead, `java MyAwesomeSearchClass %1`??

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very simple example of what you are looking for. When you run the SearchFiles, it will prompt you for a method name (string) and directory. It will scan the path for all *.java files and look for a the "method name" you specify. Keep in mind this is a string search so you potentially will get false positives.

```
public class SearchFiles
{

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    SearchFiles searchFiles = new SearchFiles();
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the method to be searched.. ");
    String methodName = scan.next();
    System.out.println("Enter the directory where to search ");
    String directory = scan.next();
    searchFiles.findFile(methodName, new File(directory));
  }

  public void findFile(String methodName, File file)
  {
    File[] list = file.listFiles(new FilenameFilter()
    {
      public boolean accept(File dir, String fileName)
      {
        return fileName.endsWith(".java");
      }
    });
    if (list != null)
      for (File javaFile : list)
      {
        if (javaFile.isDirectory())
        {
          findFile(methodName, javaFile);
        }
        else
        {
          scanFile(javaFile, methodName);
        }
      }
  }

  public void scanFile(File file, String method)
  {
    Scanner scanner = null;
    try
    {
      scanner = new Scanner(file);

      while (scanner.hasNextLine())
      {
        String nextToken = scanner.nextLine();
        if (nextToken.contains(method))
        {
          System.out.println(String.format("file found in %s" , file.getAbsolutePath()));
        }
      }
      scanner.close();
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
      // you will need to handle this
      // don't do this !
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This looks like an easier way to handle your requirement.